# Making ls output like dir /b /s

Tags: linux

How can I tweak the output of `ls` in Linux so that it looks like the output of the command `dir /b /s` in Windows?

`dir /b /s` output as follows:

```
C:\MinGW>dir /s /b 
C:\MinGW\COPYING 
C:\MinGW\COPYING.LIB
C:\MinGW\doc 
C:\MinGW\include
```

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -print
```

This should produce the same output as `dir /s/b`

Comment: Not quite. The paths are displayed relative to `.`, not `/`. `find BACKTICKpwdBACKTICK -print` would work. But that's a bit more complicated than just using `ls` and I don't think exact conformance to `dir`'s output format is a strict requirement.

Comment: @sepp2k: Given your last sentence, I'm confused why you point out the first. Find is a generally much more useful tool than ls for cases similar to this.

Comment: @jrtokarz: You don't need the dot or -print, they're the default, so just "find".

Comment: @Roger: I believe the search path is required in most `find` versions (except GNU).

Answer (score 2):

`ls -R` lists all files and subdirectories recursively. With `ls -R1` you get the same, but only one file per line.

Neither makes the output look exactly like that of `dir /b /s`, but it should be close enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -1
```

or

```
ls -1d "$PWD"/*
```

Comment: `/S` is the dir equivalent of `-R` even if the OP's example output does not make that clear.

Comment: `ls -1` does not work recursively (as required). `ls -1R` would work recursively, but its output will look quite different to `dir /s /b` (which shows the absolute paths for each file). `ls -1d "${PWD}/*` also misses two things: the recursion and matching normal files (your `-d` limits output to directories only). –

Answer (score 1):

It depends, how hard the requirement is to get "equivalence" to `dir /b /s`... These ones come pretty close (they'll have no backslashes as directory separator though, and the output order will be a bit different [`dir /b /s` outputs 'sibling' directories first, before diving into each one to show their content]). The second one is just a fallback in case your version `find` doesn't default to `-print` action (most do though):

```
find $(pwd)
find $(pwd) -print
```

**UPDATE:** I had a typo in above commands originally. I typed curly brackets "{}" instead of round ones "()" how they ought to be. Thanks to *grawity* for spotting this.

Comment: It's `$PWD`, uppercase.

Comment: @grawity: you're right and wrong at the same time. `$PWD` or `${PWD}` would return the content of an **environment variable** (the current directory). This is what you have in mind. `pwd` is a little commandline utility ('print working directory') which also outputs the current directory path. Using it as `${pwd}` or as \`pwd\` would return the **result of that command**, which in this case has the same effect as using `$PWD`. So my version will definitely work, and your comment was not appropriate in this context.

Comment: Correction: `$(pwd)` returns output of `pwd`, and `${pwd}` returns the value of `$pwd`. Notice the difference in brackets.

Comment: @grawity: D'oh! You're right of course. (I do it right whenever I need to do it in a shell. Heaven knows why I did it wrong when typing it into the text edit field....) I'll correct my comments so it will not confuse other readers.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work, from the command line:

```
find|awk "/^\.\//{print\"$PWD\"substr(\$0,2)}"
```

Comment: Why would you not just use `-printf` instead?

Comment: Because I'm new and do things the hard way. I've added this line to my `.bashrc` which seems to do the trick: `alias lsb='find . -printf "$PWD/%P\n"'` Is this what you mean? Thanks for the tip!